# How much would you ask a company if they want these features in their app?

Tags: ecommerce

I am working on a project for a company. This project is a progressive web app to connect manufacturers and distributors it does not have any buying or selling features in simple words it is eCommerce but doesn't have the buying and selling or maybe you can call it a simplified version of Alibaba but it does have the following:

Admin Area

Product Category Registration

Product Registration

Public Area

Home Page

Seller Registration

Buyer Registration

Text Chatting between buyer and sellers

Search Facility

By region

By product

By category

By seller name

By buyer name

Seller Profile page

Buyer Profile Page

AI-based user recommendation manufacturer to distributor and vice-versa.

Also, they use their own version of Google material design which is super complex

What I am thinking is how much money should I charge the company to complete this project as I am the only one working on it I have to deal with both front-end and back-end. All I want to know from you guys is how much is my work on this project worth how much money should I charge them as I am totally unsure of my work's worth and I might over or under evaluate it.

So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have done some research and have come to a conclusion that you should charge them at least $20,000 of course they'll try to do some bargaining but try to get at least $17,000 out of this project as the project is super huge and could take around a year to complete for a single developer working on it all alone.

I got into a similar project with a bit lesser functions and I had 3 developers working with me it wasn't like a job or something it was a contract we we get 50% advance before the work starts and then at the end of the work get the rest of the 50% we were paid $22,000 each and the project was completed in 2 months.

I was able to charge $2,000 more than the cost that I told you because of my well-known senior developer status all in all your final offer should not be less than $17,000.

Comment: Thanks, for such a helpful answer.

Comment: Hey, have you done something like an select a user's region from an image and show it as precisely as a city without using any APIs like google maps?

Comment: @Stranger No I haven't seen nor have I made such a detailed API, library, or any other service which lets the user mark their region from a picture of a map as precisely as a city in my vast 15 years in web development.

Comment: Oh ok Thanks a lot.

Comment: What If I make something like this how much money should I charge? and how much time would it take for me to develop it all alone? or maybe if there is another developer working along with me how much time should it take?

Comment: Well, this is something pretty complex and would require a lot of hard work for completion. If I were you I would want at least $50, 000 for a project like this and I would definitely not do it all alone I would want a team of more than 5 people working with me. If you were to work on it all alone it would take you around 5 years to complete and if there is another developer working along with you It might be done in around 2 - 3 years.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance and keep in touch with me.

Comment: Hey can I know your email address so we can communicate further in the future?

Comment: @Stranger Sorry but I don't share my email address nor any personal contact information online if you need help just ask a question on this site I am online for 6 hours daily.

Comment: OK no problem thanks

Comment: Can you please tell me how much should I ask for a project which consists of parts above and the territories part what should be the least possible bid for this project will $50,000 be alright?

Comment: @Stranger No, It is definitely most certainly not alright ask them at least $70, 000 for this project and that should be your final bid not less than that.

Comment: Thanks for the help